# UIPrintInteractionController always shows current WKWebView instead of iFrame content

Tags: ios, iframe, wkwebview

I've got two web pages: `/invoice_display`, which shows an invoice and has a "Print" button. The "Print" button creates a hidden iFrame and sets the source to `/invoice_printable` which has a `window.print()` embedded in the page that executes on page load.

This all works great in a web browser, but I'm having an issue when loading in a `WKWebView` on iOS. The issue is that the `UIPrintInteractionController` preview always shows `/invoice_display` instead of `/invoice_printable`.

Here's the current code:

### `/invoice_printable`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

### `UIViewController`

```
- (void)createWebView {
    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:@"window.print = function() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage('print') }"
                                                  injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd
                                               forMainFrameOnly:NO];
    [config.userContentController addUserScript:script];
    [config.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"print"];

    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:config];
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    webView.UIDelegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    self.webView = webView;
}

- (void)printCurrentPage {
    UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    printInteractionController.printFormatter = self.webView.viewPrintFormatter;
    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Print failed: %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Print cancelled");
            }
        }
    };

    [printInteractionController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
    if ([message.name isEqualToString:@"print"]) {
        NSLog(@"Got a 'print' message from the web page");
        [self printCurrentPage];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Got a web page message other than 'print'");
    }
}
```

How can I get the printable iFrame content to show up in `UIPrintInteractionController` instead of the originating web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I'm using `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:` to detect the iFrame. I then use the iFrame's `NSURLRequest` to get the web page as `NSData`, which I then pass into a `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` as an `NSString`. Finally, that formatter gets passed to the `UIPrintInteractionController`. Whew.

Here's the working code:

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
        NSLog(@"Got an iFrame: %@", navigationAction.request.URL.absoluteString);
        // Save this request so we can use it later for invoice printing
        self.printRequest = navigationAction.request;
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
    }
}
```

And then once the web page calls `window.print()`...

```
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
    if ([message.name isEqualToString:@"print"]) {
        NSLog(@"Got a 'print' message from the web page");
        [self GETWebDataWithRequest:self.printRequest];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Got a web page message other than 'print'");
    }
}

- (void)GETWebDataWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *getDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            NSLog(@"Got web data for url: %@", request.URL);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self printCurrentPageWithData:data];
            });
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Web data error: %@", error);
        }
    }];

    [getDataTask resume];
}

- (void)printCurrentPageWithData:(NSData *)webData {
    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *markupTextPrintFormatter = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:htmlString];
    UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    printInteractionController.printFormatter = markupTextPrintFormatter;

    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Print failed: %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Print cancelled");
            }
        }
    };
}
```